# Java conditional compilation with subclasses

Tags: java, conditional-compilation

My apology if this was already asked somewhere else but I couldn't find it.

Basically, I would like to know whether a Java class with conditional compilation (for the purpose of removing all traces of a snippet of code in class files) will work on its subclasses.

For example, let's have class *A* and its subclass *B* implemented as follows:

```
public class A {
    protected static final boolean ASSERTS = false;

    protected A() {
        if (ASSERTS) {
            System.out.println("A: ASSERTS enabled.");
        }
}

public class B extends A {
    protected B() {
        if (ASSERTS) {
            System.out.println("B: ASSERTS enabled.");
        }
}
```

It's clear that nothing will be printed out. But, will their class files include the compiled if-condition?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you run the Java disassembler `javap` and check for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not.

You should try creating your .class files and then de-compile it using a decompiler or simply go to javadecompilers.com and upload your class file to confirm your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just compiled the class in IntelliJ, then decompiled the `.class` file to see if it contained the statement(s).  It did not.

I suspect this is compiler dependent (i.e. the Java Language Specification makes no statement about whether or not these things must be included, so they are free to choose), and that you could probably find a compiler which *would* include these statements however.  I was using Corretto Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

if make sources based on your code

```
public class A {
protected static final boolean ASSERTS = false;

protected A() {
    if (ASSERTS) {
        System.out.println("A: ASSERTS enabled.");
    }
}

public static class B extends A {
  protected B() {
      if (ASSERTS) {
          System.out.println("B: ASSERTS enabled.");
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and compile with javac, then with FALSE we have byte-code

```
  public class A {
    protected static final boolean ASSERTS;
    protected A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #2                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
  }
```

with TRUE we get compiled byte-code below

```
public class A {
  protected static final boolean ASSERTS;

  protected A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #2                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       7: ldc           #4                  // String A: ASSERTS enabled.
       9: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      12: return
}
```

so that on javac level such optimization works but for guaranty it is better to remove code parts on level of sources before compilation for instance with [preprocessor](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor)

Answer (score -1):

Java doesn't support such macros like c, c++
You can use flags to enable or disable assertions at runtime but no macros